# How can I import submodules of pandas without importing matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I am using pandas 0.14.1 on a webserver to process reports from a SQL database.

I do not need any plotting facilities, but matplotlib is *always* imported.

How can I import only the modules that I need to do the following?

```
df = pd.io.sql.frame_query(query, con=conn)
df['colname'].apply(somefunc)
df.set_index('colname')
print df.to_html()
```

I am constantly having to add the following hack to all of my report generating scripts:

```
import os
os.environ['MPLCONFIGDIR'] = '/tmp/'
```

Before I import pandas. What can I do to avoid this?

Here's my webserver error log when I omit this hack:

```
File "/var/www/scripts/myscript.py", line 46, in index\n    from pandas.io import sql
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>\n    from pandas.core.api import *
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 9, in <module>\n    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 15, in <module>\n    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 38, in <module>\n    from pandas.core.series import Series
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2524, in <module>\n    import pandas.tools.plotting as _gfx
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 26, in <module>\n    import pandas.tseries.converter as conv
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tseries/converter.py", line 7, in <module>\n    import matplotlib.units as units
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 774, in <module>\n    rcParams = rc_params()
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 692, in rc_params\n    fname = matplotlib_fname()
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 604, in matplotlib_fname\n    fname = os.path.join(get_configdir(), 'matplotlibrc')
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 253, in wrapper\n    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 478, in _get_configdir\n    raise RuntimeError("Failed to create %s/.matplotlib; consider setting MPLCONFIGDIR to a writable directory for matplotlib configuration data"%h)
RuntimeError: Failed to create /var/www/.matplotlib; consider setting MPLCONFIGDIR to a writable directory for matplotlib configuration data
```

Further detail: Platform is Ubuntu 12.04LTS which has a fairly old version of matplotlib. [Recent versions fix this error by creating a temp file](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/832). However it still sucks that matplotlib is running in my webserver when I don't need it.

Comment: have you tried importing only what you need. eg. `from pandas.io import sql`? (instead of `import pandas as pd`)

Comment: @hitzg yes, it still ends up importing matplotlib via `import pandas.core.common as comm` which then imports all of pandas `import pandas as pd`

Comment: Hack idea: what happens if you add an empty `matplotlib.py` to your script directory?  That should shadow the system `matplotlib`.

Comment: you problem is that the webserver user (`www-data` I presume) has no .matplotlib config file in it's home (which is `/var/www`, the web root). easy fix is to place a .matplotlibrc into the application dir and set backend that doesnt require a display (like `Agg`)

Comment: I'll try both of these and post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the answer is upgrade matplotlib to a version that creates a writable configuration directory on startup if the default locations are not available. This is a pain if you're using your linux distribution packages (matplotlib v1.1.1) Versions after 1.3.1 should be fine.

Both suggestions in the comments do not fix the problem.

Changing the mpl config to use a different display driver like `Agg` does not stop matplotlib from trying to create a config directory.

Adding an empty matplotlib.py file breaks pandas because it requires the matplotlib.units module for datatype conversion.

So to avoid this until upgrading matplotlib, the `os.environ['MPLCONFIGDIR'] = '/tmp/'` hack works fine, but we have to remember to put it in every file that uses pandas on our webserver. (or create our own custom module that hides all of this)